# How to know what version of UglifyCSS was installed?

Tags: ubuntu, npm, uglifyjs, uglifycss

I has installed `UglifyCSS` globally with command:

```
npm install -g uglifycss
```

How can I get current version of installed `UglifyCSS`?

**P.S.**

Version of `UglifyJS` I check with command:

```
uglifyjs -V
```

But when I try similar command for `UglifyCSS`:

```
uglifycss -V
```

I had an error:

```
unable to process "-V" with Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '-V'
```

Same error when I try `-v` and `--version`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no command line option to get the installed version. The only valid options are `--max-line-len`, `--expand-vars`, `--ugly-comments` and `--cute-comments`.

However, you can run `npm list -g` or `npm list` to get list of installed packages and their version numbers. Or you can even add the package name to query a specific package, e.g. `nmp list uglify-js`.

Comment: you can also add --depth==0 so it only gives you the packages and not their dependencies.